# Await insert to finish before asserting

Tags: scala, integration-testing, h2, slick

I have a model and wrote tests before I started. Now my problem is: While the functionality works, my tests are non-deterministic. Most of the time they work, but sometimes they don't. I assume it's because of the `Future`

But let's show you what I mean by example:

```
before {
    db.run(animals.createTable)
  }

  after {
    db.run(animals.dropTable)
  }

  "An animal" must "have a unique id" in
  {
    val setup =  DBIO.seq(
      animals.insert(Animal("Ape")),
      animals.insert(Animal("Dog"))
    )

    db.run(setup)


    val result = db.run(animals.tableQuery.result).futureValue
    result shouldBe a[Seq[_]]
    result distinct.length shouldEqual 2
    result(0).id should not equal result(1).id
  }
```

I assume sometimes the `db.run(setup)` finishes in time, but sometimes it does not, hence I then get an AssertionException "expected length was 2, actual 0". As said, to me it looks like a "race condition" here (I know that is not the correct terminus ;)).

So, what I tried was simply awaiting the result of the insert-statement like so:

`Await.ready(db.run(setup), Duration.Inf)`

But that doesn't change a thing. So why is that? Can somebody explain to me why Await does not block here? I assumed this to block and only execute the lines that come after, when the insert had been executed.

I also tried wrapping the assertions in an `.onComplete`-block, but no luck either.

Any hints for me?

Comment: You should try mixing in the `IntegrationPatience` trait which instructs `futureValue`s to wait longer for a result. But if `Await`ing with infinite duration doesn't do the trick then it seems like a logic problem, because when the duration is infinite, the next line won't execute unless the operation finished. You can also try to do `Await.ready(db.run(setup).recover { case t => println(t) }, Duration.inf)` to make sure that there aren't any exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your issue is that sometimes your before hook has not finished either, since it's also async. I would suspect that if you add an `Await.ready` to your future in the before block along with your setup block, the problem will go away.